# Remapping Alt+ijkl to arrow keys

Tags: release-loki

What is the best way to remap Alt+ijkl to produce up/left/down/right arrow key presses? So far I've tried:

1. **xbindkeys/Gnome keyboard shortcut settings + xte/xdotool/xmacro**. Both xbindkeys and the Gnome keyboard shortcut settings can launch other programs just fine, and xte/xdotool/xmacro can all generate key presses just fine from the terminal, but for whatever reason combining them doesn't work.
2. **xmodmap**. The xmodmap solutions I've seen all remap Alt to something else, so while the fake arrow keys work I can no longer use Alt for anything else.
3. **AutoKey**. Autokey works flakily (~50% of key presses).